# How do I get search engines to index all language variants of a page?

Tags: http, internationalization, seo

I have a page that has translations available in a variety of languages. I'm trying to be a good HTTP citizen:

- I return the correct version based on the `Accept-Language` header
- I return a `Vary: Accept-Language` header

(The users of my site can override these settings in their user profiles, but I don't think that's relevant to the discussion at hand.)

How do I get search engines to index all the variants?

**Later**

The [Google Webmaster Central Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/search?q=accept-language) recommends using URLs and *against* using `Accept-Language` to detect language. Their solution would certainly work, but it seems anti-HTTP.

Comment: Selecting language by negotiation is fine in theory but lousy in practice. A document in a different language usually *really is* a different resource, so it should have its own url.

Comment: Kudos for using HTTP in a proper way. It's so sad to see how Google dictates ignoring such useful HTTP features. Meanwhile it seems that Google learned a bit more of HTTP: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/01/crawling-and-indexing-of-locale.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly recommended to use different domains for different languages:

- `fr.mysite.com` or `mysite.fr` for **French**
- `ru.mysite.com` or `mysite.ru` for **Russian**

A less preferred method that would still work for SEO is to use sub-directories to differentiate:

- `www.mysite.com/fr/` for **French**
- `www.mysite.com/ru/` for **Russian**

Sometimes `session` is used to identify the language being served. This is not recommended for SEO - search engines will not see different languages.

References:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192
http://www.seomoz.org/blog/seo-guide-international-versions-of-websites

Comment: do you have a reference for this?

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/seo-guide-international-versions-of-websites

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the "Canonical Tag" and the "Alternate Tag". Thats what a SEO would say. What they mean by this is

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yourdomain.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.yourdomain.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.yourdomain.com" />
```

If you like more, you can also use other toplevel domains like this

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yourdomain.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.german-keyword.de" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.yourdomain.com" />
```

**Put this tags in the head of every version of your website!**

Here is how it works:
Canonical tells google to use all incoming linkjuice on this page to "this specific canonical url". This includes duplicate content pages, which may exist trough struggling with GET parameters! This will drop all your duplicate content worries.

Then, see trough the "Alternate Tag" which version is good for which language and show this specific url (eg. de.yourdomain.com) in the countries SERPs.

Here a the two common sources on this topic:

1. http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=de&answer=139394
2. http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077

Comment: Certainly the `canonical` and `alternate` tags help, but they're still different URLs. It seems that the answer is that in this case, Googlebot does not love HTTP.

Comment: Of course there are multiple URLs. It's still best for User Experience. You can target your audience by country